# How to annotate multiple variables extracting from Tuple?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there any way to add types to values extracting from `Tuple` from function like below?

```py
from typing import Tuple

def f() -> Tuple[int, int, int]: 
    return 1, 2, 3
```

##### Desired way:

```py
i: int, j: int, n: int = f()
```

##### What I already tried:

```py
i: int, j: int, n: int = f()
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```py
i: int, j, n = f()
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```py
i, j, n: int = f()
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```py
(i: int), (j: int), (n: int) = f()
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I'm unclear why you would need to type annotate the return value. At least in Pycharm, it can already infer that the return type of `f()[0]` is int.

Comment: Unluckily Jupyter notebook cannot infer return type that's why I'm used to add types manually.